# Connect local(host) network from android application located in AVD Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I want to develop an android application with Eclipse, Android 4.1.2, and ADT 20.

The application is supposed to connect to an Oracle database on the local network (10.10.x.x).

I will not use Oracle Mobile Server (maybe in the future).

I first tried to connect Oracle using ojdbc14 as I had done in my previous Java applications.

It didn't work.

Then for trial purposes, I wanted to make a ping access to the local PC. It didn't work either.
In the run configurations of eclipse, I added `-dns-server 10.10.X.X` and added necessary uses-permission tags to the manifest xml. No successful connection.

I've also tried port redirection, though I am not sure whether I did it correctly.

How can I access the local network (my PC) from android application running on AVD emulator?